# Updating images without recompiling all source files in XCode

Tags: xcode

When I update spritesheets (.PNG files) in an XCode project I should "Clean" project to have images updated in app, but cleaning forces XCode to recompile all source files which takes lots of time.
Can I clean just image cache and use previous compiled sources?